# multiple weighted coin toss probabilty

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The experiment consists of ten pairs of pictures of which five pairs should be seen as identical and five others where a difference might be seen. 65 people are shown the 10 sets and answer either yes - they are different or no they are identical. The percentage of correct answers for the identical pictures correctly seen as identical 57, 74, 60, 75, 88% and for pictures correctly seen as different 58, 40, 51, 38, 52%

The other results are that 2 people got 2/10 right, 1:3/10  11:4/19 8:5/10  22:6/10 9:7/10  3:8/10  3:9/10  4:10/10

Let us take the three people who got 9 out of 10. One could multiply the probabilities of getting each one right to arrive at an overall probability. But some were more accurate than others in that they answered more difficult questions correctly. Multiplying the probability of each one getting it right and dividing by three gives an inaccurate picture of the true probability. And so forth for the others. How do you weight the probabilities correctly and determine if there is a probability p = .05 of these people being able to see a difference.

Comment: The last paragraph should read: Let us take the three people who got 9 out of 10. One could ADD the probabilities of each one getting nine right and divide by three to arrive at an overall probability. However, this doesn't work for the people who got two right. Using this method you arrive at an improbable large probability for something which was rare. How do you weight the probabilities correctly and determine if there is a probability p = .05 of these people being able to see a difference.

Comment: This answer is bad written in a sense i cannot understand.....